# SSIS DTS_E_OLEDBERROR and Out of Memory Error transferring SQL Server records to Oracle Database

Tags: sql-server, oracle, visual-studio-2015, ssis

I'm trying to import around 5M records from a SQL Server database to an Oracle Database and am getting an `Out of Memory` error.  See details below. I've tried a number of recommendations already from researching, but haven't found a solution.

Things I've tried/Notes:

1. Source is SQL Server using "OLE DB Source" and the "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Driver
2. Destination is Oracle Db using "OLE DB Destination" and the "Oracle Provider for OLE DB" driver.
3. I tried the "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle" as the destination instead.
4. I tried increasing the "Defalut Buffer Size" the Data Flow to 100 MB
5. I tried increasing the "DefaultBufferMaxRows" to 10 M rows.
6. The computer is 64-bit with 16GB of RAM and has Windows 7 Professional.
7. I have both the 32-bit and 64-bit Oracle Client installed
8. The SSIS project's "Run64bitRuntime" property is set to True.
9. I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Any ideas?

Here are the pertinent messages.

> Warning: 0x80047076 at Data Flow Task Load PFILSA OneLink Table 
>       2012, SSIS.Pipeline: The output column "DateTime" (137) on output 
>       "OLE DB Source Output" (105) and component "OLE DB Source" (94) is 
>       not subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused 
>       output column can increase Data Flow task performance.
>
> Error: 0xC0202009 at Data Flow Task Load PFILSA OneLink Table 2012, 
>       OLE DB Destination [12]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE 
>       DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x8007000E.
>
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Cursor Engine"
>       Hresult: 0x8007000E  Description: "Out of memory.".

Comment: Batch this code. Its clear from this error (`Source: "Microsoft Cursor Engine"  
Hresult: 0x8007000E  Description: "Out of memory."`) that the engine is attempting to read all of the rows at once on the SQL Server side - or at least more rows than you can hold in your free memory. Change your pipeline to move, oh, 100,000 rows at a time by using some variables and a loop. Exit the loop when the rows moved are less than 100,000.

Comment: @LaughingVergil Why use a loop if you can set a batch size in SSIS? What is the batch size when you extract data from the data source? The query that you run against the SQL Server, if you run it in the SSMS, do you get the same "out of memory" error?

Comment: SSIS and Memory: http://sql-ramblings.blogspot.com/2010/12/ssis-and-memory.html
Out of Memory Error (bUFFER sWAPPING )- SSIS: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/496c59f2-e635-4144-97cf-3eec5401faa3/

Comment: I don't get the out of memory error in SSMS. Though the source isn't a query. I'm actually pointing it to the whole table in.SQL server. I guess I could try to loop or batch it. However I could see where to apply a bath size?

Comment: I have another server or computer that SQL server. Would it be better to move the source data to that box instead? Would it then utilize that computers memory so there isn't competition on the local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Your package is trying to read too much data into memory than what your machine can handle before inserting into your destination. Open the destination and set it use **fast-load** data access mode, set **rows per batch** to 10000 and **maximum insert commit size** to 100000

Comment: I tried changing it to fast-load, but now am getting an error: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. check each OLE DB Status value, if available. No work was done"

Comment: Did you also change the rows per batch property and maximum commit size?

Comment: Yes. Changed as you instructed and got the error:

An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle"  Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.". Error at Data Flow Task Load 1 [OLE DB Destination [12]]: Failed to open a fastload rowset for ""MySchema"."MyTable"". Check that the object exists in the database.

Comment: I'm certain the object exists in the database. Not only did I double check, I was able to select it from the "Name of the table or the view" drop down

Comment: Try Rebuilding the solution so it will update the meta-data

Comment: So after more research, found out the fast-load option cannot be used with an Oracle driver. The destination is an Oracle Db